# Jsoup - get the action of a form

Tags: forms, action, hidden, jsoup

Basically, I have a form.

```
<form id="frm1" action="random.php" >
<input ... />
<input ... type=hidden name=id value=random_number />
</form>
```

I need to get the two random values. The action and the hidden value called id. The id of the form does not change. It is always frm1.
I am totally confused on how to do this. I can select the form but don't know what to do
from there.

Hoping for help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't already you should look at this http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation

There's a method on `Element` called `attr(String key)`
In your case `formElement.attr("action")` should return "random.php"

To get the second random number, if there is not an id on the element, you can use `formElement.children()` and just iterate the child elements looking for whatever qualifiers you want and pull out the value attribute.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. Instead of using formElement.children(), since I knew the name of the input, I used formElement.select("input[name=id]").first()